# BASH to compare two fields integrating informations from another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, highest

I have the following two text files:

fruits.txt

```
nectarine      strawberry
orange         peach
grape          apple
mango          watermelon
```

numbers.txt

```
strawberry    57
apple         48
mango         40
peach         44
watermelon    60
nectarine     46
orange        72   
grape         39
```

In fruits.txt I want to keep only one of the 2 fruits per line. The one **removed** should be the one with the **higher** corresponding number (*c.f.* numbers.txt). 
The output would look like:

```
nectarine
peach
grape
mango
```

How could I proceed to achieve this in bash?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Post your research efforts along with the question

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {num[$1]=$2; next} {
print (num[$1] < num[$2] ? $1 : $2)}' numbers.txt fruits.txt
```

```
nectarine
peach
grape
mango
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `read` and `while` loop.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read numbers.txt into associate array
declare -A a
while read k v; do
    a[$k]=$v
done < numbers.txt

# process the fruits.txt
while read l r; do
    (( a[$l] > a[$r] )) && l=$r
    echo $l
done < fruits.txt
```

will give the desired output